# Appending data to the same file

Tags: java, file, append

Having trouble with appending the data to the same file, though tried but getting the error.

Here is my code

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
            URLShortener u = new URLShortener(100, "https://is.gd/");

            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new 
File("C:\\data.txt"))));
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new 
FileWriter("C:\\dataoutput.txt")))

                    {
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String shortenedUrl = u.shortenURL(line);
                    System.out.println(new String(
                            "URL:" + line + "\t" + shortenedUrl + "\tExpanded: " + u.expandURL(shortenedUrl)));
                    bw.write(shortenedUrl + "\r\n");

                    System.out.println("Appending new data to shortUrls");
                    try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\dataoutput.txt", true);
                            BufferedWriter bappend = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bappend))
                    {
                        pw.println(shortenedUrl + "\r\n");

                    } catch(IOException e) {

                        e.getMessage();
                    }    

                }
            }
    }
```

Here is the error. My output file is pointing to the dataoutput file and it still does not get it to append.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 10, length 0
        at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
        at com.misc.tests.URLShortener.sanitizeURL(URLShortener.java:101)
        at com.misc.tests.URLShortener.shortenURL(URLShortener.java:67
        at com.misc.tests.URLShortener.main(URLShortener.java:151
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with appending to the same file. The error is reported in `String shortenedUrl = u.shortenURL(line);`   - maybe the line is not an URL?

Comment: Could It be that you are reading blank line?

Comment: line is a string from the data.txt file, I have declared it in the beginning of getting data from the file - and the file has millions of Urls. I am actually using the existing code from GITHUB below. Then I have created a test method to generate the shortener Urls.
https://gist.github.com/rakeshsingh/64918583972dd5a08012

Comment: I got the StringIndexOutOfBoundsException solved - this is because of the empty lines in my data file. I have fixed it. However, I am unable to append to the file. for some reason - I just cannot add new data to the existing file.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it by my self - here is the answer. What I was doing is - On line 7 I have created 'bw' pointing to file 'dataoutput.txt' and in line 19 I created 'fw' pointing to the same file and file is open at 7. so, I have changed it to the pw instead and this worked fine - I am able to append data to the file.

```
{
    private static final String INPUT_FILE =
            "C:\\PowerShell Automation\\data.txt";
    private static final String OUTPUT_FILE = 
            "C:\\PowerShell Automation\\dataoutput.txt";

    public static void main( String args[] ) throws IOException {
        URLShortener u = new URLShortener( 100, "https://is.gd/" );

        System.out.println( "Appending new data to shortUrls" );

        try( BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream( new File(
                        INPUT_FILE ) ) ) );
            // *** open for append
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter( new FileWriter(
                    OUTPUT_FILE, true ) );
            )
        {
            String line;
            while( ( line = br.readLine() ) != null ) {
                String shortenedUrl = u.shortenURL( line );

                System.out.println( new String(
                        "URL:" + line + "\t" + shortenedUrl + 
                        "\tExpanded: " + u.expandURL( shortenedUrl ) ) );

                pw.println( shortenedUrl );
            }
        }
    }
```